# How do I position an element next to overflow:scroll

Tags: css

I need help with position.

This is setup code

```
<div style="background-color: gray; width: 100%; height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; ">

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; background-color: rgb(248, 83, 83); width: 300px; position: sticky; bottom:0; ">

  <div style="width: 100%;  border: 1px solid black; ">Something</div>
```

And this is code where is problem

```
    <ul >

      <div *ngFor="let x of elementList" >

        <li style="border: 1px solid black; position: relative; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;"> <span>{{x.Title}}</span>

          <ul>

            <div style="background: pink; position: absolute; right: -50px; top: 0;">

            <li >{{x.Subtitle}}</li>

            <li >{{x.Subtitle}}</li>

            <li >{{x.Subtitle}}</li>

            <li >{{x.Subtitle}}</li>

          </div>

          </ul>

        </li>

      </div>

    </ul>
 
  </div>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; display: flex; gap: 10px; padding: 5px;">

    <span class="material-icons-outlined">

      arrow_back

      </span> <span>Hide navigation</span>

  </div>

</div>

<div style="background-color: rgb(152, 247, 152); width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

</div>
```

I working on this for past 5h so can you help me?
This is full code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5XGN.png)

What I want is set list outside of contaner next to scroll

Comment: Please provide more info, code.

Comment: Do not share images of code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML;

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="middle">
     <div id="inner">Something</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li>List item one</li>
       <li>List item two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

To force a container to have a scrollbar, the inner content needs to have a width greater than it's container. Therefore I set the inner div's width to 120% and then put overflow: scroll on the middle div.

Styling;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background-color: gray; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex; 
}

#middle {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  background-color: rgb(248, 83, 83); 
  width: 300px; 
  position: sticky; 
  bottom:0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#inner {
  width: 120%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pjtqyoc1/25/)